# Python encoding issue involving special characters

Tags: python, encoding

I am running Win7 x64 and I have Python 2.7.5 x64 installed. I am using Wing IDE 101 4.1.

For some reason, encoding is messed up.

```
special_str = "sauté"
print string
# saut├⌐
string
# 'saut\xc3\xa9'
```

I don't understand why when I try to print it, it comes out weird. When I write it to a notepad text file, it comes out as right ("sauté"). Problem with this is that when I use BeautifulSoup on the string, it comes out containing that weird string "saut├⌐" and then when I output it back into a csv file, I end up with a html chunk containing that weird bit. Help!

Comment: You can control the input and output encoding using the `codecs` module, or by using the string class's `encode`/`decode` methods. It would be easier to provide a working solution if we could see the part of your code that handles input and output.

Comment: I suggest you read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the encoding of the source file so Python can properly decode your string literals.

You can do this with a special comment at the top of the file (first or second line).

```
# coding:<coding>
```

where `<coding>` is the encoding used when saving the file, for example `utf-8`.